# Multiple join in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to do a multiple join like this

```
SELECT * FROM (((Customer FULL JOIN Booking ON Customer.ID = Booking.CustID) 
FULL JOIN Flight ON Booking.FlightID = Flight.ID) 
FULL JOIN FlightRoute ON Flight.RouteID = FlightRoute.ID)
```

But it is syntactically incorrect according to mysql. Please help

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `FULL JOIN` in MySQL. It's convoluted but a `FULL JOIN` is equivalent to a `UNION ALL` between a `LEFT JOIN` and a `RIGHT JOIN`, using a condition to remove duplicates. It's late in the day and the thought of your 3 `FULL JOIN`s  in that statement is hurting my head.

You do say in Conrad Frix's answer that removing the `FULL` makes it work, if it does then you have misunderstood how `FULL JOIN`s and `INNER JOIN`s work.

For the first `FULL JOIN` it would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers c
   LEFT JOIN Booking b ON c.ID = b.CustId
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Customers c
   RIGHT JOIN Booking b ON c.ID = b.CustId
WHERE c.ID IS NULL
```

Use that basis to form the rest of your statements.

Answer (score 0):

When i was looking about MySql and FULL Join i found this article which explains a number of ways to emulate FULL JOIN in Mysql. I think it could be usefull to you.

[How to simulate FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL isn't my area of expertises but I don't think MySQL supports full joins. I found a simple article that details some alternatives.

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/